# System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox hide frame

Tags: c#, winforms

On the System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox, is there any way to hide frame around it? I tried changing the FlatStyle but that does not do what I want. 
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that the point of a group box? If you don't want the frame why not just use a Panel with a Label for the title?

Comment: There are many scenarios in programming, the fact that "the point" of something is a fixed paradigm does not mean that you cannot change it a little bit and get something else, that solves a different problem... which is what the answer left by Bobso provides and what I needed. thanks for your input!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `Panel` is probably a better option, but if you really need a `GroupBox` for some reason, you can modify the code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/cfd34dd1-b6e5-4b56-9901-0dc3d2ca5788/) to create a subclass which doesn't paint the border at all.   Specifically, you'll want to override the `OnPaint` method.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with subclasses, adapt the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042058/6674014). Remove the size and rect, and the line draws.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know this is not possible.

Try using a panel instead.

You could put a label at the top if you want and they practically do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is not (short of custom painting code).  I think a `Panel` be better control to use here, although you don't get the text header (just add a label if you need one).