# Retrieve GroupBox border size

Tags: c#, winforms

I am manually resizing a GroupBox based on its content.
To give it the proper size, it needs to be `Content.Size + Border.Size`.

How do I figure out what the size of the GroupBox border is?

Comment: Why don't you set the `GroupBox`'s `ClientSize` property? It should do all that's necessary to take the border size into account by making sure that the size of the client area matches the size you gave. And why not use the `AutoSize` property in the first place?

Comment: Why not simply `AutoSize = true`? Though I recall [why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18308883/1997232).

Comment: Please, have a look at `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation` class

Comment: Extend group box add `BorderThickness` and override `Paint` event  and just like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-border-on-a-group-box) change `width` in `DrawLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`DisplayRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) property as a base for the calculations:

```
var bounds = groupBox.Bounds;
var displayRect = groupBox.DisplayRectangle;
var borderSize = new Size(bounds.Width - displayRect.Width, bounds.Height - displayRect.Height);
```